Prove that if $A\in GL_n(\Bbb C)$ has an eigenvalue of geometric multiplicity $\ge2$, then $A^{-1}=Q(A)$ for some $Q\in\Bbb R_{n-2}[X]$.
Here is the problem:

Let $A\in M^{\mathbb{C}}_{n\times n}$ be an invertible matrix such that $A$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$ with geometric multiplicity of at least $2$. Prove that there exists a real polynomial $Q$ with degree less that or equal to $n-2$ such that $A^{-1}=Q(A)$.

Using properties of the Jordan form, I was able to show that the minimal polynomial of $A$ is of the desired degree and the constant term is nonzero (because $A$ is invertible) so this is almost good, but we need the polynomial to be real.
The minimal polynomial clearly need not be real, so I guess this approach is not good.
How can we prove that there exists such a polynomial, a real polynomial?

This is not true. Let $n=3$ and $A=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda,\lambda,\mu)$ such that $\lambda\ne0$, $\mu\ne0$, $\lambda\ne\mu$ and $\lambda+\mu\not\in\mathbb R$. By construction, $A$ is invertible and its eigenvalue $\lambda$ has geometric multiplicity $2$. Its minimal polynomial is $m(x)=(x-\lambda)(x-\mu)=x^2-(\lambda+\mu)+\lambda\mu$.
Suppose $A^{-1}=Q(A)$ for some real polynomial $Q$ of degree $\le n-2=1$. Since $A$ is not a scalar multiple of the identity matrix, $\deg(Q)$ must be equal to $1$. Hence $Q(x)=ax+b$ for some $a\in\mathbb R\setminus0$ and $b\in\mathbb R$. Now let $f(x) =xQ(x)-1=ax^2+bx-1$. Then $f$ annihilates $A$. Therefore $m$ divides $f$. It follows that $f=am$ and $\lambda+\mu=-\frac{b}{a}\in\mathbb R$, which contradicts our assumption that  $\lambda+\mu\not\in\mathbb R$.
